# Token Generation in Client server application C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, .net-2.0

I need to develop an application to authenticate the request. For which i wanted to go with token based authentication. 
My first question is.
Do token needs to be generated at Server side? 
or the token is generated by client application and I have to decrypt it using private public/key?

Is there any other approach where key sharing is not mandatory?

Comment: You will want to look at this: [identityserver3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3)

Comment: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/

This is a good start point to understand the whole process, they also have some examples in a git repo showing the flow of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Have a look at this talk by Daniel Roth. It's a really nice talk to get you started. https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-504

Comment: Here is a nice article for web api 2. This is helpful for me http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/. And to answer your question tokens was generated in server side